# multiple addTextChangedListener for multiple edittext

Tags: android

I have 3 EditText named editTextA , editTextB and editTextC .
I want to do when text change on either one edit text, the other two will update.
t
I could done with single addTextChangedListener changing editTextA and updating editTextB. But when I add another addTextChangedListener to editTextB, it do not work. My app look hanged but not crashed. my logcat show something like this many times

```
  Background partial concurrent mark sweep GC freed 23189(905KB) AllocSpace objects, 0(0B) LOS objects, 40% free, 23MB/38MB, paused 28.101ms total 157.246ms
```

Can I actually use different listener for different editText view change?

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    inputa = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputa);
    inputb = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputb);
    editTextA = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.a);
    editTextB = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.b);
    editTextC = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.c);

    editTextA.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            String entera = editTextA.getText().toString();
            double usera = Double.parseDouble(entera);

            String stringofa = inputa.getText().toString();
            double a = Double.parseDouble(stringofa);

            String stringofb = inputb.getText().toString();
            double b = Double.parseDouble(stringofb);

            double resultb = usera * b / a;
            editTextB.setText(String.format("%.3f", resultb));

            double usertotal = usera + resultb;
            editTextC.setText(String.format("%.3f", usertotal));
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });

    editTextB.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
            String enterb = editTextB.getText().toString();
            double userb = Double.parseDouble(enterb);

            String stringofa = inputa.getText().toString();
            double a = Double.parseDouble(stringofa);

            String stringofb = inputb.getText().toString();
            double b = Double.parseDouble(stringofb);

            double resulta = userb*a/b;
            editTextA.setText(String.format("%.3f", resulta));

            double usertotal = userb + resulta;
            editTextC.setText(String.format("%.3f",usertotal));
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Where is `calculateb` EditText?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code suggests you are creating a recursive loop, whereby changing the text in `editTextA` changes the text in `editTextB`, which then changes the text in `editTextA`, and so on *ad infinitum*. This eventually result in an out of memory error.

```
ditTextA.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    //...
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        //...
        editTextB.setText(String.format("%.3f", resultb));
    }
//...

editTextB.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    //...
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        //...
        editTextA.setText(String.format("%.3f", resulta);
    //...
```

One solution could involve creating a `boolean` switch to ensure that each `setText()` is called only if the switch is `true`

**Edit:**
Verify text has changed before updating.

```
e1.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    //...
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        if(!editable.equals(e2.getText())) {
            e2.setText(editable);
        }
    }
});

e2.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    //...
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        if(!editable.equals(e1.getText())) {
            e1.setText(editable);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Oh you are right. Are there method to differentiate if the input is from user? like the onProgressChanged method from SeekBar?

Comment: @SimonHo Not that I am aware of unfortunately. It is very easy to create an infinite loop with `TextWatcher` - the methods I have successfully used in the past include a `boolean` switch, and/or a check to see whether the text needs to be changed (i.e. `if (!editText.getText().toString().equals("expected text")) { //update text }`

Comment: @PPartisan: I have exactly same problem. Could you please elaborate your answer.

Comment: Take a look at my edit. The basic idea is you only want to update the other EditText if the text differs. That will stop an infinite loop.